# static creator method for each implementing class of interface

Tags: java

I need to make a server which can process different kinds of messages.
The messages come in a stream of bytes and are identified by the first 2 bytes (opcode).
So I have this interface

```
public interface Message<T> extends Encodeable {

    Message<T> act(T actOn, UserCommandInvocationProtocol<T> protocol);

    byte[] encode();  // from Encodeable

}
```

The server should create a Message according to the opcode in the stream.
my current solution is hashmap that maps each opcode to a matching lambda, for example:

```
    addMessageDecoder(3, nextByte -> {
        String[] strArr = strPtrnDec2.decodeNextByte(nextByte);
        return strArr != null ? new LoginMessage(strArr[0], strArr[1]) : null;  // LoginMessage implements Message
    });
```

the interface used for the lambdas:

```
 interface MessageDecoder<T> {

    Message<T> decodeNextByte(byte nextByte);

}
```

Notice how I have `encode()` in the `Message` interface, so each message can turn to bytes.
What I would have liked to have is `static decode()` for each message that creates a matching Message object, If Java had allowed it, it would have looked something like this:

```
public interface Message<T> extends Encodeable {

    Message<T> act(T actOn, UserCommandInvocationProtocol<T> protocol);

    byte[] encode();

    static Message<T> decodeNextByte(byte nextByte):  // does the job of interface MessageDecoder<T>

}
```

What would be the best practice here? or maybe my current solution is fine?
Thanks

Comment: [Abstract factory pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) may be appropriate?

Comment: @Abra Well yeah, I guess that's what I'm doing here, MessageDecoder is actually the factory.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a default static method in newer versions of Java, but that’s probably not what you want.

You need another class that knows how to create instances of your messages, with a switch hat will read in a couple of bytes, then determine which message you’re trying to decode and then pass it to that. You won’t be able to do that with one single level of indirection. In effect, you want a MessageFactory to do your parsing for you based on the bytes read at the top level.

That said, if you’re looking to do this more widely, you should probably consider a library like protobuf which will do this for you.

Answer (score 1):

There are times when a simple static method will do to sort all this out, and attempts to magical syntactic sugar does not help.  there is no getting around the fact that you have to read two bytes, and associate that with an object instance.  So write a simple static factory method that does this.  It reads two bytes, and returns an instance of the right object.

But where do you specify the associations?  This can either be done in a global static hashtable, or each class can specify their associated bytes, and an initializer method will walk through the known classes and build that map.  There is not a whole lot of advantage to either way, because at the end of the day, what is required is knowing the list of implemented classes.

I always just make a single static factory method.  In there is a simple if-then-else statement that tests the incoming bytes and returns the right instance.   If there are a lot of classes, I will build a some sort of hashtable to speed this lookup.  But if the number of classes is small, e.g. less than 30, then a simple if-then-else code is probably fast enough.

The advantage of the static factory method is that there is one place where the code is associated with the class, and that is in that one method.

Comment: switch case wouldn't work in my case because I want the handler to not be implementation specfic. So it's actually an abstract class and the deriving class must implement setFactories() method which adds MessageDecoder according to his defined messages. But I get the point, thanks.

Comment: Right, the factory is implemented by the implementation and not the abstract base.  There is no working around it: either all the classes needs to register themselves so that such a factory can work (as I guess you have done), or else something needs to iterate through the existing classes using reflection to make such a factory work.